# Python image processing : Help needed for corner detection in preferably PIL or any relevant module

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm new to image processing and got to do corner detection for this image:
[image]

In this image, I need to extract the starting and end points of each line segment or the coordinates of the corners. This is just a small part in my project and I'm stuck on this because I've no experience in image processing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's a solution, using [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org):

```
from skimage import io, color, morphology
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = color.rgb2gray(io.imread('6EnOn.png'))

# Reduce all lines to one pixel thickness
snakes = morphology.skeletonize(img < 1)

# Find pixels with only one neighbor
corners = convolve2d(snakes, [[1, 1, 1],
                              [1, 0, 1],
                              [1, 1, 1]], mode='same') == 1
corners = corners & snakes

# Those are the start and end positions of the segments
y, x = np.where(corners)

plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray, interpolation='nearest')
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: corners of line segments]

Comment: Nice - great use of convolve here - I'd have ended up using 8 different ``np.rolls`` so I'm a better person for having read your answer! ;)

Comment: Glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome), which comes with both the Harris corner detector and the Shi-Tomasi corner detector.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not find ALL the corners in the image.

Using **Harris corner detection**, one can find ***all*** the possible corners. Since OP's choice of modules is not restricted, I chose to perform the following using the OpenCV library.

RESULT:

[image]

Every single corner present in the image is identified correctly.

[THIS PAGE](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html) provides details of the algorithm and the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether I understand the question correctly, but I think a low efficiency way to do it is to scan through each pixel and check the 4 directions around that pixel. If 2 non-opposite directions (i.e up & left or up & right etc.) are coloured, then it is a corner.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would work if the lines were of 1 pixel thickness. That is rarely the case and the example image is also not an exception (zoom in). Working algorithms are way more complicated ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection)).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I'd assume that you could parse the png header to retrieve the width/height of the image (take a look at [this RFC for png details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2083)). Combine this with the bit depth of the image and you should be able to determine where each corner is with simple math. Once you've found the corner, you should be able to follow the line using a simple algorithm checking neighboring pixel data.

This also sounds like homework. If so, you should tag it as such.